# TypeError: 'numpy.uint32' object is not iterable in using numpy.full function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy, typeerror

In some lines within a huge python script, there is a 3d array of 74537000 elements that are all float numbers:

```
import numpy as np
prop_shape = [74537000, 3]  # to produce this however a long script is written and this will be printed (just before the controversial line below) in the first run of the code assuming it's a vector quantity like position.
prop_in_dtype = np.float32  # position array with the shape (74537000, 3) is made up of float32 values. In general, however, prop_in_dtype is changing across the script due to the nature of the array
```

When we are trying to make an identical array whose elements are all -1, we can use numpy as follows:

```
.
.
.
my_array = np.full(tuple(prop_shape), -1, prop_in_dtype)
.
.
.
```

While running this, I have the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DLA_DM.py", line 19, in <module>
    settings_centroid.init()
  File "/usr5/username/settings_centroid.py", line 43, in init
    part=gizmo.io.Read.read_snapshots(species, snapshot_value_kind, snapshot_number, simulation_directory='.', snapshot_directory='output/', simulation_name='', properties=properties, element_indices=None, particle_subsample_factor=0, separate_dark_lowres=True, sort_dark_by_id=False, convert_float32=True, host_number=1, assign_host_coordinates=True, assign_host_principal_axes=False, assign_host_orbits=False, assign_formation_coordinates=False, assign_pointers=False, check_properties=True)
  File "/usr5/username/simulation/gizmo/gizmo_io.py", line 649, in read_snapshots
    element_indices, convert_float32, header)
  File "/usr5/username/simulation/gizmo/gizmo_io.py", line 1164, in read_particles
    part[spec_name][prop] = np.full(tuple(prop_shape), - 1, prop_in_dtype) 
TypeError: 'numpy.uint32' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Huh?  You've added a print *after* a line that generates an exception, and are claiming to show output from that print - how could that possibly be true, due to the exception on the previous line?

Comment: Hi Jason, I don't understand  the exception produced on the line. What are 'numpy.uint32's?

Comment: It will be much easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You probably don't need to use your big array in the example.  You should be able to reproduce the problem with an array with shape, say, (5, 3).

Comment: Also, when you get this problem solved, you will quickly run into another: you can't subtract a nonzero scalar from a `dia_matrix`.  If you try, you'll get the error `NotImplementedError: subtracting a nonzero scalar from a sparse matrix is not supported`.  If you really need an array full of -1, use a regular numpy array.

Comment: Initially I had used numpy.zeros instead of scipy.sparse.dia_matrix. However, due to MemoryError complain, I had to change my methodology given the huge RAM space needed to run overhead calculations.

Comment: A `dia_matrix` that is full of the value -1 will require *more* memory than a regular numpy array.  Sparse matrices are useful when most of the values in the matrix are 0.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the error message with:

```
In [174]: tuple(np.uint32(1))                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-3420675a1788> in <module>
----> 1 tuple(np.uint32(1))

TypeError: 'numpy.uint32' object is not iterable
```

So my guess is there's something wrong with the `prop_shape` variable.

Comment: All I know is that prop_shape is a list object containing 3d coordinates of positions.

Comment: I mean the first element is the number of positions and the second element is the dimensionality.

Comment: Test `tuple(prop_shape)` by itself.  The fact that you get the same error when you change the sparse call to `full` is further proof that the problem is with that `tuple` function argument.

Comment: Before the mentioned line, print(tuple(prop_shape)) gives the tuple (74537000, 3) as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`prop_shape` is iterating in the original code. Sometimes it's a single integer (for scalar quantities e.g. 74537000) and sometimes a two-element list (for vector quantities, e.g. [74537000, 3]). I was assuming that it's fixed to be a two-element list (hence a vector). That's why tuple of a single scalar would give such error if the scalar is not a `float32` dtype. To avoid that, I made an `if statement` where each time it checks for the dtype of the variable before making the array:

```
if isinstance(prop_shape, list):
    my_array = np.full(tuple(prop_shape), -1, prop_in_dtype)
else:
    my_array = np.full(prop_shape, -1, prop_in_dtype)
```

However, as I said in my comment to Warren's suggestion, I end up with a MemoryError as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DLA_DM.py", line 96, in <module>
    gizmo.plot.Image.plot_image(settings_centroid.part, 'dark', 'mass', settings_centroid.image_kind, [0,1], settings_centroid.dimensions_select, settings_centroid.distance_max, settings_centroid.distance_bin_width_generic, distance_bin_number=settings_centroid.distance_bin_number, part_indices=part_indices, write_plot=write_plot, plot_directory=plot_directory, background_color=background_color, use_column_units=False, center_position=settings_centroid.center_position, rotation=settings_centroid.rotation, property_select={'mass.bound':[1e9,1e13]}, subsample_factor=subsample_factor, image_limits=settings_centroid.image_limits_xy, hal=settings_centroid.hal, hal_indices=settings_centroid.hal_indices, hal_position_kind=hal_position_kind, hal_radius_kind=hal_radius_kind, return_halo_info=settings_centroid.return_halo_info_value_dark)
  File "/usr5/username/simulation/gizmo/gizmo_plot.py", line 825, in plot_image
    settings_centroid.init()
  File "/usr5/username/settings_centroid.py", line 43, in init
    part=gizmo.io.Read.read_snapshots(species, snapshot_value_kind, snapshot_number, simulation_directory='.', snapshot_directory='output/', simulation_name='', properties=properties, element_indices=None, particle_subsample_factor=0, separate_dark_lowres=True, sort_dark_by_id=False, convert_float32=True, host_number=1, assign_host_coordinates=True, assign_host_principal_axes=False, assign_host_orbits=False, assign_formation_coordinates=False, assign_pointers=False, check_properties=True)
  File "/usr5/username/simulation/gizmo/gizmo_io.py", line 649, in read_snapshots
    element_indices, convert_float32, header)
  File "/usr5/username/simulation/gizmo/gizmo_io.py", line 1171, in read_particles
    part[spec_name][prop] = np.full(prop_shape, -1, prop_in_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 309, in full
    a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
MemoryError
```